# compare const char * string to uint32_t value at compilation

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have version in 2 different descriptions, one as string and the other as value for example:

```
static const char * versionStr = "03-October-2022" ;
static const uint32_t versionVal = 20221003 ;
```

How can I test if they are equal (in compile time) to make sure I didn't update one without the other?

Solution in pure preprocessor smarts, I'm bound to C++98.

Quite a challenge :)

Comment: You're better off computing one from the other at program startup.

Comment: Step 1 is to declare both of them as `constexpr`. Step 2: make sure your compiler implements C++20, since the `strcmp()` C library function is not `constexpr`, and it appears that `std::equal` is `constexpr` only in C++20. Step 3: some elbow grease, and `constexpr` code that constructs a string from the integer (including mapping month numbers to month names), and then using `std::equal` to compare the end result.

Comment: why on earth do you use C++98 nowadays? The oldest "usable" C++ standard is C++11 which add so many useful things from C99. And why the C tag in a C++ question? Remove it

Comment: @phuclv some call it backward compatibility and others from time to time need to support old environments. C and C++ preprocessor basically the same beside of small differences therefore the c tag. please try answer the questions and not lecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare them at compile-time. But, what you can do is build up the values using preprocessor macros for the common elements, thus reducing the possibility of making a mistake, eg:

```
#define c_day           03
#define c_year          2022
#define c_month         10
#define c_month_name    October

#define STRINGIFY(param) #param
#define make_versionStr(y, m, d) (STRINGIFY(d) "-" STRINGIFY(m) "-" STRINGIFY(y))

#define make_versionVal_concat(y, m, d) (y ## m ## d)
#define make_versionVal(y, m, d) make_versionVal_concat(y, m, d)

static const char* versionStr = make_versionStr(c_year, c_month_name, c_day);
static const uint32_t versionVal = make_versionVal(c_year, c_month, c_day);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/sn10y0)